# django celery cannot start worker

Tags: django, celery, worker

I am having an issue with starting up my celery worker for my django project. Thank you for giving any help here.

I think I shut down the celery process inappropriately (ctrl+c first, and ran the "celery -A proj worker " command again before it was shut down completely). Since then I have never been able to start up my celery worker. It basically gives no response from the command line, not moving forward, no error, and nothing happens literally. It is just stuck there.

but "celery worker" can start successful, only "celery -A proj worker" fails

I also tried to reinstall my celery and rabbitmq, but this doesn't help either.

Does anyone know what could be wrong here? How can I fix this issue? Thank you very much for your help.

my celery.py:

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'webSite.settings')

app = Celery('webSite')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

sen

Comment: Have you tried running it with `-l debug` and inspecting the logs?

Comment: Just to be clear, you should replace `proj` with the name of your django project.

Comment: Can you please post your celery.py ?

Comment: @sytech, yes, I am aware of that, I have been using my own project name. Actually, my celery was working fine before I inappropriately shut it down last time.

Comment: @schillingt, I have not setup the debug yet, will try it. But any command with "-A webSite" will get stuck, I had to terminate my terminal.

Comment: @2ps,  I have posted my celery.py in my edits.  I also tried different backend settings, currently i have django_celery_results extension installed. I also tried: app = Celery('webSite', backend = 'django-db')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your help, I have figured out how to figured out the issue.

So, each time I got stuck with starting the celery worker I closed my terminals, and therefore next time the process still hang there. What solved the problem for me is kill the process while the celery process is hanging there with "kill -9".

This solved my problem, but thank you all for the help.

sen